# MultiSelect value of hidden column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that on `DataBindingComplete` event I hide one column (it's the first column of my grid data):

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
}
```

Now, when I do a multi-select of a few rows and cells, I need to get only values of that hidden "ID" column for all selected cells and rows. I know how to get values of the "ID" column when I select whole rows:

```
string Ids;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    Ids += row.Cells[0].Value + ", ";
}
```

But since `MultiSelect` allows combined selection (whole row + cell from another) I do not know how to get values for the "ID" column when there is only a cell selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access rows which have a cell selected by checking the `SelectedCells` for each cell's `RowIndex`. If you gather all unique row indices into a list, then you can use that list nearly the same way you already are:

```
List<int> selected = DataGridView1.SelectedCells
                                  .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                  .Select(cell => cell.RowIndex)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .ToList();

string Ids;

foreach (int rowIndex in selected)
{
    Ids += DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value + ", ";
}
```